# Representation of a group

Tags: group-theory

The elements of a transformation group are usually represented by linear operators acting on a linear vector space (LVS). We usually represent the elements of a group as square matrices acting on (the elements of) a LVS. Can't we use other linear operators to represent the elements of a group?

Comment: Do you have a particular group in mind? Most group have many representations.

Comment: Could the close voters pleas clarify what exactly is off topic about this question? Asking about alternative representations of a group is legitimate. Voted to leave open

Comment: @Dilaton The close votes are to move this question to math.SE because this is a purely mathematical question.  There are certainly physical consequences of this stuff, but the OP does not ask about physics in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all linear representations can be given in terms of matrices (unless you consider infinite dimensional matrices). For instance unitary representations of Lorentz group cannot be given in terms of matrices, since all these representations work on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces (it is related with the fact that the group is not compact). So the used operators are unitary operators.  As I said, if you fix a Hibertian basis, in principle,  you may represent these operators as infinite dimensional matrices, but I cannot really imagine a situation where such a cumbersome  representation could have some technical interest, for the Lorentz group at least.

Dropping the requirement of **unitary** operators, you may also have finite dimensional representations of the Lorentz group where operators can be represented as matrices (obviously, once you have fixed a basis). The simplest case are spinorial representations.

Restricting to deal with matrix representations (and this is the case for irreducible unitary representations of compact groups), the used matrices have necessarily to be **square** matrices, because they have to be invertible as the elements of the represented group are invertible.

Comment: @V.Moretti- Can't I use differential operators for representation of a group?

Comment: Technically speaking the answer is negative. If you want that these operators are the self-adjoint generators of a strongly continuous unitary representation of the group, in general, differential operators are not enough. You should take self-adjoint extensions of suitable differential operators, that in turn, are no longer differential opertaors!